# How to automate pressing right command key on a macbook using python

Tags: macos, macbook, automation

I am doing some automation for my testing work on mac. While a lot of tools and libraries are available to simulate button pressing on keyboard(like pyautogui and osascript), I could not find a way to press the **right** command key as all the options I could find only pressed the left command key(using the keyword 'command').

My testing involves pressing (right command key)+R.

Comment: looks like apple decided not to provide different keycodes for left and right command, so I dont think you can do this.